# Raspberry Pi 4 not booting after the welcome screen splash

Tags: pi-4, boot, boot-issues

I shut down my Raspberry Debian OS (properly using Shut Down) to attach a [DHT22 Temperature and Humidity Sensor](https://www.amazon.se/gp/product/B078SVZB1X/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to the board.

After connecting the sensor, I started the Pi. I get a colorful splash screen at first. After a few seconds, the Welcome screen appears for a second, and that is the last I see. The power LED is working and red. But the green Act LED stops after a few blinks.

The [SD card is completely new](https://www.webhallen.com/se/product/271797-Minneskort-microSDHC-16GB-forinstallerat-med-NOOBS) and is 16GB.

I reinstalled the OS on the SD card, to no avail. For the time being, I do not have another SD card to test whether that is the problem.

I also tried uncommenting the `#hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in the config file.

I am just wondering what I have done wrong. Is it possible that such a normal temperature sensor damages the board or the SD card?

Raspberry Pi Model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 8GB

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried formatting the SD card and re-installing the Raspberry Pi OS. [This is a recording of what happens when I start the Pi](https://streamable.com/19gv0t).

**UPDATE 2:**

I purchased another Micro SD card (32GB) and gave it another go. I got the same results plus one more error upon booting for the first time  (something complaining about being Read-Only and failing to write `wtmp`).

Enabling `ssh` when writing the image did not make a difference either. This was suggested by one of the comments.

So, if it is the Pi board that is damaged due to connecting the sensor, how is one supposed to confirm that? There does not seem to be a lot to do if the SD card cannot boot the system.

And I don't think there are any compatibility issues because I was able to boot and do some work before connecting the sensor.

Comment: Perhaps you connected the sensor incorrectly and have damaged the Pi.  No point in us wasting time in guessing.  It is down to you to provide information if you want help.

Comment: disconnect the DHT22 sensor board

Comment: @jsotola I did it right after the first time the Pi didn't boot.

Comment: @joan it could be. But without the SD card, I do get the Raspberry boot screen (the one that says there are no SD cards.) I just hope it is not the Pi that is damaged.

Comment: @joan I am ready to provide information. How can I do that?

Comment: @joan I have updated the question with the link to a recording of what happens after I format the SD card and re-install the OS. Please take a look when you have time. Much appreciated!

Comment: enable ssh - and connect to the pi that way - it may be a display problem

Comment: @Bravo this message gave me hope. I will try it out as soon as I am back home today. Where should I enable the ssh?

Comment: you can do it when you flash an image if you use the raspberry pi imager - failing that, you just need to create an empty file called `ssh` in the boot partition, then stick it back in your pi and boot

Comment: @Bravo I tried this to no avail, unfortunately. The green LED stops blinking after a while as you see in the video.

Comment: Not sure what the blinking of the led has to do with attempting ssh

Comment: It may not have nothing to do with that. It’s me who’s a newbie. Is there anything else to test?